# How to Handle Two Different Response in Retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, jsonschema2pojo

I followed [this](http://codingsonata.com/retrofit-tutorial-android-part-2-post-requests/) to POST Data Using Retrofit2

I Used [JSON POJO](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to Parse my POST and GET files

So Here If Data inside the Records Is there I will get This Kind of Response

```
{
"status": "200",
"response": [{
        "cnt_id": "201",
        "phn_no": "3251151515",
        "dat_cnt": "Reset Password request Said to Mail"
    },
    {
        "cnt_id": "209",
        "phn_no": "555465484684",
        "dat_cnt": "Hi DEMO User , Congratulations! Your account has been created successfully."
    },
    {
        "cnt_id": "210",
        "phn_no": "4774748",
        "dat_cnt": "Hi XYZ , Congratulations! Your account has been created successfully."
    }
]
}
```

If there is no Data I will get

`{"status":"204","response":{"msg":"No Content"}}` or 
`{"status":"400","response":{"msg":"BadRequest"}}` or 
`{"status":"401","response":{"msg":"Unauthorized User"}}`

So Here I can eable to Parse the data which is there in the status 200 but when Status is not equals to 200 I want to Handle them

I tried with

```
   status = response.body().getStatus();
   if(status.equals("200")) {
      List<Response> resList =  response.body(). getResponse();

            for(int i = 0; i<resList.size(); i++)
            {.
             .
              ..
             .
            }
        }

        else {
             //not Implemented
             }
```

now what should I write in Else I used response data in POJO which are not equals to 200 but I its asking for list

**Update**

com.example.Example.java

```
public class Example {
    @SerializedName("status") @Expose private String status;
    @SerializedName("response") @Expose private List<Response> response = null;
}
```

com.example.Response.java

```
public class Response {
    @SerializedName("cnt_id") @Expose private String cntId;
    @SerializedName("phn_no") @Expose private String phnNo;
    @SerializedName("dat_cnt") @Expose private String datCnt;
}
```

Comment: Can you please keep method of the Api call .

Comment: Its there in that Example link http://codingsonata.com/retrofit-tutorial-android-part-2-post-requests/... if you have similar data,,, come to chat I will give

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
public class Example {
    @SerializedName("status") @Expose private String status;
    @SerializedName("response") @Expose private Object response = null;
}

public class Response {
    @SerializedName("cnt_id") @Expose private String cntId;
    @SerializedName("phn_no") @Expose private String phnNo;
    @SerializedName("dat_cnt") @Expose private String datCnt;
}

public class ResponseError{
    @SerializedName("msg") @Expose private String msg;
}
```

And Your callBack methods should be like

```java
new Callback<Example>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
       if (response.isSuccessful()){
          Example example = response.body();
          Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

          if (example.status.equals("200")) {
              TypeToken<List<Response>> responseTypeToken = new TypeToken<List<Response>>() {};
              List<Response> responseList = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(example.getResponse()), responseTypeToken.getType());
          } else {
              //If for everyOther Status the response is Object of ResponseError which contains msg.
              ResponseError responseError = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(example.getResponse()), ResponseError.class);
          }
       }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {
        //Failure message
    }
}
```

Comment: my I know How to use this ResponseError  in Example  class

Comment: Than what's the problem

Comment: you have added this line @SerializedName("response") @Expose private String response = null; its fine.. Shall I need to add another for ResponseError?

Comment: If you have your own than it's fine. Don't create one. Use that only. If not than create. Else you'll not be able to parse the response from Gson.

Comment: Actually What ever is there its calling List.. `public List<Response> getResponse() {
        return response;
    }` for non array List I need to add Response Error?

Comment: To check that we require your method structure.

Comment: I have followed completely.. that tutorial code http://codingsonata.com/retrofit-tutorial-android-part-2-post-requests/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174619/discussion-between-brijesh-joshi-and-dont-be-negative).

Comment: @RohitRawat What's your issue?

Comment: Is there also a way for handling two different responses when using kotlins coroutines instead of callbacks?

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by fetching `errorBody()` with help of Retrofit2.

Make one POJO model class with name `RestErrorResponse.java` For handle this Response.

> {"status":"401","response":{"msg":"Unauthorized User"}}

And follow information given below:

```
 if (response.isSuccessful()) {

        // Your Success response. 

 } else {

        // Your failure response. This will handles 400, 401, 500 etc. failure response code


         Gson gson = new Gson();
         RestErrorResponse errorResponse = gson.fromJson(response.errorBody().charStream(), RestErrorResponse.class);
                    if (errorResponse.getStatus() == 400) {
                        //DO Error Code specific handling

                        Global.showOkAlertWithMessage(YourClassName.this,
                                getString(R.string.app_name),
                                strError);

                    } else {
                        //DO GENERAL Error Code Specific handling
                    }
                }
```

I handled all failure response by this method. Hope this can also helps you.

Comment: actually I am using Example and Response class where should I update this `{"status":"401","response":{"msg":"Unauthorized User"}}` and what should be in else...?

Comment: @Don'tBenegative You need to create Seperate class to handle this error response.

Comment: Print log of response.errorBody().charStream() in else part of above code.

Comment: You are on the Right way. Replace "RestErrorResponse" with your "Example" class. and then get Your error message by errorResponse.getResponse().getMsg(). get it??

Comment: Shall I need to Create again two Class?Example =RestErrorResponse and Response=Response2?

Comment: whats that error. First Print log of "response.errorBody().charStream()" in else part of above code. And check that will you getting proper failure response here or not??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174618/discussion-between-bhoomika-patel-and-dont-be-negative).

Answer (score 2):

```
class Response<T> {
        private String status;
        private T response;

        private boolean isSuccess() {
            return status.equals("200");
        }
    }

    class ListData {
        private String cnt_id;
        private String phn_no;
        private String dat_cnt;
    }

    class Error {
        private String msg;
    }

    public class MainResponse {
        @SerializedName("Error")
        private Error error;
        @SerializedName("AuthenticateUserResponse")
        private List<ListData> listData;
    }

@POST("listData")
Call<Response<MainResponse>> listData();
```

Comment: hi user@user3235116 Once Check my Update and Can you suggest me where I need to change

Comment: Thanks for Answer ... can you suggest me In my code..?

Answer (score 1):

you can use different pojo class to handle error msg

```
status = response.body().getStatus();
if(status.equals("200")) {
    ResponseSuccess res =  response.body();
    for(int i = 0; i < res.response.size(); i++){
        Log.d("TAG", "Phone no. " + res.response.get(i).phn_no);
    }
} else {
    Converter<ResponseBody, ResponseError> converter = getRetrofitInstance().responseBodyConverter(ResponseError.class, new Annotation[0]);
    ResponseError error;
    try {
        error = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
        Log.e("TAG", error.response.msg);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        error = new ResponseError();
    }
}
```

success pojo class

```
public class ResponseSuccess {
    public String status;
    public List<Response> response;
    public class Response{
        public String cnt_id;
        public String phn_no;
        public String dat_cnt;
    }
}
```

error pojo class

```
public class ResponseError {
    public String status;
    public Response response;
    public class Response{
        public String msg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually Before Response class I have status?,, So I Have Two class https://pastebin.com/raw/fQMFAUXW now I need to create 3rd class? I tried to add you code in Example or Response class I am facing errors

Comment: you can create single class for success and error like I have defined please check

Comment: Hi @VinayRathod Now I have 3 calsses...MainResponse,ResponseSuccess,ResponseError  but in Main Response what should I define in Main Response... I already Defined reesponse List in calls https://pastebin.com/raw/xB0Y7nmp..  So if there is no response what should I do

Comment: you don't have to create `MainResponse` since it is cover in `ResponseSuccess` class

Answer (score 0):

So in your case there is possibility of getting response tag type as `String/List<Response>`. so you declare response tag type as `Object`

`@SerializedName("response") @Expose public Object response;`

and write code in onResponse method of retrofit following code snippet

```
if (response.body().response!=null &&  response.body().response instanceof Collection<?>) {
            //if you find response type is collection then convert to json then json to real collection object
            String responseStr = new Gson().toJson(data.diagnosis.provisionalDiagnosis);
            Type type=new TypeToken<List<Response>>(){}.getType();
            List<Response> responseList=new Gson().fromJson(responseStr,type);
            if(responseList.size() > 0){
                binding.phoneTv.setText(responseList.get(0).phnNo);
            }
        }
```

I found this is easy way to handle single tag with multiple type

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code for response code 200, 401, 400

```
public void getMusicDetail(String path, String id) {
        if (AppUtil.isInternetAvailable(context)) {
            binding.loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonObject.put("token", Prefs.getPrefInstance().getValue(context, Const.TOKEN, ""));
                jsonObject.put("song_id", id);
                jsonObject.put("menu_id", path);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                binding.loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String params = jsonObject.toString();
            final RequestBody get_music_detail = RequestBody.create(params, MediaType.parse("application/json"));
            APIUtils.getAPIService().get_now_playing(get_music_detail, "Tracks").enqueue(new Callback<MusicResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<MusicResponse> call, @NonNull Response<MusicResponse> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                        if (response.body().getStatus() != null && response.body().getStatus().equals(200)) {
                            if (response.body().getData() != null && !response.body().getData().isEmpty()) {
                                songs = response.body().getData();
                                binding.songPlayPauseNowPlaying.setSelected(!MediaController.getInstance().isAudioPaused());
                                Glide
                                        .with(Durisimo.applicationContext)
                                        .load(response.body().getData().get(0).getSongImage())
                                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                                        .centerCrop()
                                        .placeholder(R.drawable.app_logo)
                                        .error(R.drawable.app_logo)
                                        .into(binding.assetImage);

                                binding.assetName.setText(response.body().getData().get(0).getSongName());
                                binding.assetArtist.setText(response.body().getData().get(0).getSongArtist());
                                binding.loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                shareDetails = "Song Name: " + response.body().getData().get(0).getSongName() + "\n\n" + "Song URL: " + response.body().getData().get(0).getSong()
                                        + "\n\n" + "Artist Name: " + response.body().getData().get(0).getSongArtist() + "\n\n" + "App Name: " + context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);

                            } else {
                                binding.loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                View dialog_view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(AppUtil.setLanguage(context, R.layout.simple_dialog_text_button), null);
                                final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                                        .setCancelable(false)
                                        .setView(dialog_view)
                                        .show();

                                if (dialog.getWindow() != null)
                                    dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().getBackground().setAlpha(0);

                                ((TextView) dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text)).setText(response.body().getMessage());
                                (dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_ok)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                ((Button) dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_cancel)).setText("OK");
                                dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_cancel).setOnClickListener(view -> {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                });
                            }
                        } else if (response.body().getStatus() != null && response.body().getStatus().equals(401)) {
                            binding.loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Intent i = new Intent(context, Login.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            getActivity().finish();
                        }else {
                            binding.loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            View dialog_view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(AppUtil.setLanguage(context, R.layout.simple_dialog_text_button), null);
                            final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                                    .setCancelable(false)
                                    .setView(dialog_view)
                                    .show();

                            if (dialog.getWindow() != null)
                                dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().getBackground().setAlpha(0);

                            ((TextView) dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text)).setText(response.body().getMessage());
                            (dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_ok)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            ((Button) dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_cancel)).setText("OK");
                            dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_cancel).setOnClickListener(view -> {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<MusicResponse> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                    binding.loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    View dialog_view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(AppUtil.setLanguage(context, R.layout.simple_dialog_text_button), null);
                    final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setView(dialog_view)
                            .show();

                    if (dialog.getWindow() != null)
                        dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().getBackground().setAlpha(0);

                    ((TextView) dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text)).setText("Something went wrong! Please try again.");
                    (dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_ok)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    ((Button) dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_cancel)).setText("OK");
                    dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_cancel).setOnClickListener(view -> {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            binding.loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            View dialog_view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(AppUtil.setLanguage(context, R.layout.simple_dialog_text_button), null);
            final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setView(dialog_view)
                    .show();

            if (dialog.getWindow() != null)
                dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().getBackground().setAlpha(0);

            ((TextView) dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text)).setText(getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet_connection));
            (dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_ok)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ((Button) dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_cancel)).setText("OK");
            dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_cancel).setOnClickListener(view -> {
                dialog.dismiss();
            });
        }
    }
```