# How To Parse Response of Multiple Types of Single Key

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

How To Parse Response of Multiple Types?

Key is like (suppose **student_list** is a key of list types when student_list is empty then it makes as a string like **student_list**=""), How to manage this types of response using Retrofit? I am using MVVM Model with retrofit.

My Response:

when I get Data into the List

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "data": [
        {
            "prod_month_total": 2989.61,
            "product": "GAS"
        },
        {
            "prod_month_total": 39566.22,
            "product": "OIL"
        },
        {
            "prod_month_total": 83912.55,
            "product": "OTHER"
        }
    ]
}
```

when List is Empty Then Response:

```
{"status":404,"data":"No result found"}
```

I am getting this Error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 23 path $.data

Comment: Please add some code samples to make us understand better.

Comment: thanks for @AtishAgarwal, This is my response which is getting from server when I get Data into the List

{ "status": 200, "data": [ { "prod_month_total": 2989.61, "product": "GAS" }, { "prod_month_total": 39566.22, "product": "OIL" }, { "prod_month_total": 83912.55, "product": "OTHER" } ] }, and when List is Empty Then Response :

{"status":404,"data":"No result found"} , and I created model class according to my response.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Handle Two Different Response in Retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51238140/how-to-handle-two-different-response-in-retrofit)

Answer (score 0):

first create the right model calss use this site http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org

than use

```
`if( reponce.isSucessful){

if(responce.status==200){
   //code here 
  }
else{
 // find the error
}
 }else
 {
//
 }`
```