# Retrofit2 Inconsistency Response from Server in android java

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am new to Android development and learning how to use Retrofit and I am having a hard time to deal with inconsistency response from the server.

There are more than two kinds of responses will be returned from the server.

May I know how to deal with this kind of server response? Should I create different data class to handle it based on the server response?

Server Response

Result - Success

```
{
    "status": true,
    "result": {
       "id": 1,
       "name": "User",
       "email": "user@gmail.com"
   }
```

}

Result - Fail

```
{
   "status": false,
   "result": []
}
```

Android Model

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    private boolean status;
    private ResultModel result;
    public static class ResultModel implements Serializable{
       private String id;
       private String name;
       private String email;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51238140/how-to-handle-two-different-response-in-retrofit

Comment: You can either post the answer here, or delete the question as a similar question has been answered elsewhere